# Makefile: difference between := and ::= assignment operators

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Gnu Makefile shows two symbols for immediate expansion, as follows:

```
immediate := immediate
immediate ::= immediate
```

Is there a difference between these two?

reference: gnu makefile manual section 3.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [section 6.2](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors):

> Simply expanded variables are defined by lines using ‘:=’ or ‘::=’
>   (see Setting Variables). Both forms are equivalent in GNU make;
>   however only the ‘::=’ form is described by the POSIX standard
>   (support for ‘::=’ was added to the POSIX standard in 2012, so older
>   versions of make won’t accept this form either).

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why they (POSIX) decided to chose ::= over simpler := ?

Comment: @Lavya: Other make implementations also had their own `:=` extensions with various meanings.  So POSIX invented new syntax to avoid stepping on any already existing toes.  See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=330 for details (and http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/make.html for the excellent activism that brought this about).

Comment: @JohnMarshall Thanks!

Comment: Interesting assertion about POSIX 2012, but not substantiated by the POSIX 2013 web site ([`make` — macros](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_05)).  There is no mention of either `:=` or `::=` in the POSIX specification that I can see, not even in the Rationale.

Comment: That [bug 330](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=330) lists `::=` as tagged _Issue 8_ and resolved as _Accepted As Marked_ in December 2011.  The POSIX 2013 web site still reflects the current Issue 7.  The [Austin Group FAQ](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/faq.html#Q8) doesn't give any clues as to in which decade we might hope to see Issue 8…  Seems like the text in the GNU Make manual was hopeful that  it would appear within the year when that text was written in January 2012.